# Controlling view from iBeacon proximity

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon

I'm playing with Corelocation and iBeacons.  I have notifications triggered when entering and exiting a region, and I can range my beacons etc.  That's all good.

However I'm getting into a mess.  I want to load a second view when near to a specific beacon, then close that view when we move away from that beacon, rinse and repeat for a second beacon.

I'm struggling with:

- how to stop triggering the change of view because the ranging doesn't stop.  If I manually stop ranging or use a bool to test if I'm already in the second view this is ok but seems messy.
- how to close the view if I move away from the beacon.  To do this I guess I can't stop the ranging, otherwise I'd not know if I moved away.

My code is below.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    // Setup Beacon Manager
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc]initWithUUIDString:@"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"];
    self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"Beacon Region"];
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
    [self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
    self.beaconStatLabel.text = @"StartLocationServices";



    //check to see if this is the first time we've run the app
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"tBHasRun"] == 0) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"tBHasRun"];  //set the time run to 1
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"firstRunSegue" sender:self];
        self.beaconStatLabel.text = @"FIRST RUN"; //set the label text
    } else {
        self.beaconStatLabel.text = @"REPEAT RUN"; //set the label text
    }

}


    //Looking for and dealing with regions

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    //looking for a region means looking for a beacon or set of beacons that share a UUID
    [self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    //if we found a region we start ranging (looking for beaocns)
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
    self.regionState.text = @"Region Entered";

    //we'll also test sending a notification
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.alertBody = @"Welcome! Go upstairs, bring beer.";
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    //we have left the region so we'll stop ranging
    [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
    self.regionState.text = @"Region Exited";

    //we'll also test sending a notification
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.alertBody = @"Thankyou for coming.  For information on our next MeetUp check our MeetUp page.";
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}

    //dealing with individual beacons

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
    //once beacons are ranged we enter this method

    //we'll grab and log the signal strength of the beacons
    for (int i = 0; i < [beacons count]; i++) {
        CLBeacon *singleBeacon = [[CLBeacon alloc]init];
        singleBeacon = [beacons objectAtIndex:i];
    }


    //we get the latest beacon in the array - the closest beacon (strongest signal)
    CLBeacon *beacon = [[CLBeacon alloc] init];
    beacon = [beacons lastObject];

    //update the info labels
    self.uuidLabel.text = beacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString;
    self.majorLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.major];
    self.minorLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.minor];

    //we store some information about that beacon
    NSNumber *beaconMajor = beacon.major;  //it's major (group) number
    NSNumber *beaconMinor = beacon.minor;  //it's minor (individual) number

    //we then call the manageBeacon method and pass through the minor, major, and proximity values
    [self manageBeaconWithMinor:beaconMinor AndMajor:beaconMajor AtRange:beacon.proximity];

}

- (void)manageBeaconWithMinor:(NSNumber *)minorNumber AndMajor:(NSNumber *)majorNumber AtRange:(CLProximity)proximity {
    //in this method we work out what do do based upon the beacon we are connected to and the range

    //for this test we'll look for the mint beacon and call a view
    if (([minorNumber floatValue] == 59204) && ([majorNumber floatValue] == 33995) && (proximity == CLProximityNear)) {
        //we are going to open up content
        [[tBGlobalStore sharedInstance]setInContentTrue];
        NSLog([[tBGlobalStore sharedInstance] getInContent] ? @"Yes" : @"No");
        //the beacon numbers match the beacon we are expecting so we'll call the next screen
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mainToContent" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Some additional information from the console, you can see it's trying to call the view more than once.

2013-11-22 15:24:56.487 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:24:56.489 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:24:56.490 testingBeacons[670:60b] Beacon at:
2013-11-22 15:24:56.490 testingBeacons[670:60b] 0
2013-11-22 15:24:56.491 testingBeacons[670:60b] has RSSI of:
2013-11-22 15:24:56.492 testingBeacons[670:60b] -75
2013-11-22 15:24:56.492 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:24:56.493 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:24:56.495 testingBeacons[670:60b] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
2013-11-22 15:24:56.497 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:24:56.498 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:24:56.498 testingBeacons[670:60b] Beacon at:
2013-11-22 15:24:56.499 testingBeacons[670:60b] 0
2013-11-22 15:24:56.499 testingBeacons[670:60b] has RSSI of:
2013-11-22 15:24:56.500 testingBeacons[670:60b] -75
2013-11-22 15:24:56.500 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:24:56.501 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:24:57.487 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:24:57.489 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:24:57.489 testingBeacons[670:60b] Beacon at:
2013-11-22 15:24:57.490 testingBeacons[670:60b] 0
2013-11-22 15:24:57.490 testingBeacons[670:60b] has RSSI of:
2013-11-22 15:24:57.491 testingBeacons[670:60b] -75
2013-11-22 15:24:57.491 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:24:57.492 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:24:57.493 testingBeacons[670:60b] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
2013-11-22 15:24:57.495 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:24:57.495 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:24:57.496 testingBeacons[670:60b] Beacon at:
2013-11-22 15:24:57.496 testingBeacons[670:60b] 0
2013-11-22 15:24:57.497 testingBeacons[670:60b] has RSSI of:
2013-11-22 15:24:57.497 testingBeacons[670:60b] -75
2013-11-22 15:24:57.498 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:24:57.499 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:24:57.500 testingBeacons[670:60b] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
2013-11-22 15:24:58.488 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:24:58.489 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:24:58.490 testingBeacons[670:60b] Beacon at:
2013-11-22 15:24:58.490 testingBeacons[670:60b] 0
2013-11-22 15:24:58.491 testingBeacons[670:60b] has RSSI of:
2013-11-22 15:24:58.491 testingBeacons[670:60b] -76
2013-11-22 15:24:58.492 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:24:58.492 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:24:58.493 testingBeacons[670:60b] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
2013-11-22 15:24:58.494 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:24:58.495 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:24:58.496 testingBeacons[670:60b] Beacon at:
2013-11-22 15:24:58.496 testingBeacons[670:60b] 0
2013-11-22 15:24:58.497 testingBeacons[670:60b] has RSSI of:
2013-11-22 15:24:58.497 testingBeacons[670:60b] -76
2013-11-22 15:24:58.498 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:24:58.499 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:24:58.500 testingBeacons[670:60b] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
2013-11-22 15:24:59.488 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:24:59.489 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:24:59.489 testingBeacons[670:60b] Beacon at:
2013-11-22 15:24:59.490 testingBeacons[670:60b] 0
2013-11-22 15:24:59.490 testingBeacons[670:60b] has RSSI of:
2013-11-22 15:24:59.491 testingBeacons[670:60b] -75
2013-11-22 15:24:59.491 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:24:59.492 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:24:59.493 testingBeacons[670:60b] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
2013-11-22 15:24:59.494 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:24:59.495 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:24:59.495 testingBeacons[670:60b] Beacon at:
2013-11-22 15:24:59.496 testingBeacons[670:60b] 0
2013-11-22 15:24:59.496 testingBeacons[670:60b] has RSSI of:
2013-11-22 15:24:59.497 testingBeacons[670:60b] -75
2013-11-22 15:24:59.498 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:24:59.498 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:24:59.500 testingBeacons[670:60b] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
2013-11-22 15:25:00.487 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:25:00.488 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:25:00.489 testingBeacons[670:60b] Beacon at:
2013-11-22 15:25:00.489 testingBeacons[670:60b] 0
2013-11-22 15:25:00.490 testingBeacons[670:60b] has RSSI of:
2013-11-22 15:25:00.490 testingBeacons[670:60b] -75
2013-11-22 15:25:00.491 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:25:00.491 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:25:00.492 testingBeacons[670:60b] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
2013-11-22 15:25:00.493 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:25:00.494 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:25:00.494 testingBeacons[670:60b] Beacon at:
2013-11-22 15:25:00.495 testingBeacons[670:60b] 0
2013-11-22 15:25:00.495 testingBeacons[670:60b] has RSSI of:
2013-11-22 15:25:00.496 testingBeacons[670:60b] -75
2013-11-22 15:25:00.496 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:25:00.497 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:25:00.498 testingBeacons[670:60b] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
2013-11-22 15:25:01.488 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:25:01.489 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:25:01.489 testingBeacons[670:60b] Beacon at:
2013-11-22 15:25:01.490 testingBeacons[670:60b] 0
2013-11-22 15:25:01.490 testingBeacons[670:60b] has RSSI of:
2013-11-22 15:25:01.491 testingBeacons[670:60b] -72
2013-11-22 15:25:01.492 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:25:01.492 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:25:01.493 testingBeacons[670:60b] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
2013-11-22 15:25:01.494 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:25:01.495 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:25:01.495 testingBeacons[670:60b] Beacon at:
2013-11-22 15:25:01.496 testingBeacons[670:60b] 0
2013-11-22 15:25:01.497 testingBeacons[670:60b] has RSSI of:
2013-11-22 15:25:01.497 testingBeacons[670:60b] -72
2013-11-22 15:25:01.498 testingBeacons[670:60b] -----
2013-11-22 15:25:01.498 testingBeacons[670:60b] ---
2013-11-22 15:25:01.499 testingBeacons[670:60b] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: Could you clarify "because the ranging doesn't stop"? Do you mean you basically see "flickering" because the Near iBeacon range can get pretty jumpy when you're on the edge?

Comment: I mean that even if you are near the beacon, inside CLProximityNear the didRangeBeacons method is continuos.  In the log you can see it trying to load the UIView over and over.

Comment: Interesting, so your calls to didEnterRegion and didExitRegion aren't "balanced"? @mrEmpty

Comment: Oh, I answered my own question :) @mrEmpty

Comment: No, they are fine.  it's the ranging method that keeps going, the didEnter and didExit trigger once upon finding or losing a UUID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

didRangeBeacons: is called once per second per beacon, and does not track changes in proximity for you.

[CLLocationManagerDelegate Reference](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html)

What I would recommend doing is encapsultating your beacon tracking in it's own class that is responsible for:

1. Managing the beacon monitoring
2. Keeping a hash of specific iBeacons and their current ranges.
3. Invoking a protocol method notifying a delegate (your view controller), or even NSNotificationCenter, when a change in range has occurred for a specific iBeacon (which you know because you are maintaining a hash of recent beacons/proximity).

Comment: That's interesting, I'll look into protocol methods.  Thank you.  I'll keep the question open for the time being in case anyone else wants to chime in.

Comment: NSNotificationCenter seems like a simple solution, re-building the app now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

We've run into a similar challenge. But there's a problem with either solution: there's a 'bug' in how Apple handles ranging and proximity, and you'll get random toggling and didExitRegion calls.

See here:

http://beekn.net/2013/11/ibeacon-tutorial-dealing-with-errors/

Your app will call a didExitRegion seemingly at random, clearly a bug, because Location Services can actually shut down entirely for a second or so.

We handled the viewController idea by stopping ranging once the viewController is pushed and then restarting it once the user closes the viewController.

1. After:
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mainToContent" sender:self];

Add:

[self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];

1. In order to restart ranging once the user closes the viewController, add:

// ViewWillAppear restarts stopRanging when OutsideViewController is pushed
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}

NOTE: If you want to close the viewController automatically based on a region change, you'll have the problem of rapid push and pull: you'll push a viewController and then it will quickly close, open, close....the problem isn't the code, it's that  the Apple API can't always make up its mind what region it's in.

POSSIBLE SOLUTION?
The "hack" might be to add a counter: what we've found is that you'll hold your phone close to a beacon and it will quickly toggle between near/immediate even though you are NOT moving your phone and the beacon signal isn't actually changing. It's an Apple "bug"! But it will only do this once or twice.

One option is to add a counter: the equivalent of "only if you've detected a region change three or four times should you trigger the event"

The other option is to add a time: "only trigger an event based on a region change if its been 4 seconds that the region has changed"

Again - the problem isn't that you'll get sudden toggles (pushing a VC or pulling it off the stack) because you're 'between zones' - the problem is:

A. Apple API can't always properly tell whether you're immediate/near/far and will suddenly change its mind

B. Apple will sometimes shut off location services seemingly randomly and for less than a second, forcing your app to re-enter a region and start ranging again.

Comment: Hello @BEEKn - seems Apple still has some work to do, it is a fairly new and obscure API so I'm not surprised.  I've decided to create my own beacon manager and handle the communication with NSNotificationCenter.  I'll post my code when it's working.

Comment: Awesome - you might also want to check out ibeacon-utils on GitHub. I actually can't get it to give permission for LocationServices but there's some good thinking in the way it's set up.